# ViewPager crashes when re-opening: NullPointerException SparseArray.get(int)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've recently switched my ViewPager's adapter from FragmentPagerAdapter to FragmentStatePagerAdapter. However, whenever I return to my ViewPager the app crashes. This was not happening with FragmentPagerAdapter. The Logcat shows:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.util.SparseArray.get(int)' on a null object reference
```

I'm in that awkward position where I don't know enough to understand what questions I should be asking. All of my searches have turned up nothing useful.

**Logcat**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.util.SparseArray.get(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment(FragmentManager.java:905)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.restoreState(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:216)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1455)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:17706)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3745)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3751)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:17684)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:415)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1454)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements  FragmentQuiz_Selection_Instruments.QuizSelectionInterface,
                FragmentQuiz_Started.OnQuizExit,
                FragmentQuiz_Selection_Topics.StartQuizInterface {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private Fragment mQuizFragment;
private Fragment mInstrumentsFragment;
private Fragment mReferenceFragment;
private ArrayList<String> mQuizSelection;
private ViewModel_ForegroundView viewModel;
private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initialise mQuizSelection
    mQuizSelection = new ArrayList<String>();
    mQuizSelection.clear();
    //Initialise bottomNavigationView
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_bottom);
    //Set Bottom-Navigation icon
    bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
    //Initialise ViewModel_ForegroundView
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModel_ForegroundView.class);

    //Initialise ActionBar
    final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

    //Initialise Top-Navigation Drawer
    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_top);
    // Set the onClickListener for the NavigationDrawer
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    // set item as selected to persist highlight
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    // close drawer when item is tapped
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    // Handle item clicks
                    int itemId = item.getItemId();
                    if (itemId == R.id.nav_top_ww) {
                        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentInstruments_WWind");
                        if (fragment == null) {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = FragmentInstruments_WWind.newInstance();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.add(mInstrumentsFragment, "FragmentInstruments_WWind");
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        } else {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = fragment;
                        }
                    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_top_br) {
                        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentInstruments_Brass");
                        if (fragment == null) {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = FragmentInstruments_Brass.newInstance();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.add(mInstrumentsFragment, "FragmentInstruments_Brass");
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        } else {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = fragment;
                        }
                    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_top_pp) {
                        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentInstruments_PercPit");
                        if (fragment == null) {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = FragmentInstruments_PercPit.newInstance();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.add(mInstrumentsFragment, "FragmentInstruments_PercPit");
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        } else {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = fragment;
                        }
                    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_top_pu) {
                        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentInstruments_PercUnp");
                        if (fragment == null) {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = FragmentInstruments_PercUnp.newInstance();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.add(mInstrumentsFragment, "FragmentInstruments_PercUnp");
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        } else {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = fragment;
                        }
                    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_top_sp) {
                        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentInstruments_StrPlu");
                        if (fragment == null) {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = FragmentInstruments_StrPlu.newInstance();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.add(mInstrumentsFragment, "FragmentInstruments_StrPlu");
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        } else {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = fragment;
                        }
                    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_top_ky) {
                        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentInstruments_Keys");
                        if (fragment == null) {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = FragmentInstruments_Keys.newInstance();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.add(mInstrumentsFragment, "FragmentInstruments_Keys");
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        } else {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = fragment;
                        }
                    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_top_sb) {
                        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentInstruments_StrBow");
                        if (fragment == null) {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = FragmentInstruments_StrBow.newInstance();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.add(mInstrumentsFragment, "FragmentInstruments_StrBow");
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        } else {
                            mInstrumentsFragment = fragment;
                        }
                    }
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, mInstrumentsFragment);
                    transaction.commit();
                    //Record foreground-fragment change
                    viewModel.recordForegroundFragment(mInstrumentsFragment);
                    //Set 'Quiz Exit' button's visibility to 'false,' set Quiz-Ext button.
                    viewModel.recordQuizBtnStatus(false);
                    setQuizExtBtn();


                    return true;
                }
            });
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(
            new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                    // Respond when the drawer's position changes
                }
                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    // Respond when the drawer is opened
                    drawerView.bringToFront();
                }
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                    // Respond when the drawer is closed
                }
                @Override
                public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                    // Respond when the drawer motion state changes
                }});

    //  Bottom-Navigation Menu
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    int itemId = item.getItemId();
                    if (itemId == R.id.nav_btm_quiz) {
                        if (mQuizFragment != null) {
                            String string = mQuizFragment.toString();
                            if (string.contains("Started") || string.contains("Topics")) {
                                viewModel.recordQuizBtnStatus(true);
                            }
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, mQuizFragment);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            //Record foreground-fragment change
                            viewModel.recordForegroundFragment(mQuizFragment);
                        } else {
                            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentQuiz_Selection_Instruments");
                            if (fragment == null) {
                                mQuizFragment = FragmentQuiz_Selection_Instruments.newInstance();
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, mQuizFragment, "FragmentQuiz_Selection_Instruments");
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                viewModel.recordForegroundFragment(mQuizFragment);
                            } else {
                                mQuizFragment = fragment;
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, mQuizFragment);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                                viewModel.recordForegroundFragment(mQuizFragment);
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_btm_instruments) {
                        viewModel.recordQuizBtnStatus(false);
                        if (mInstrumentsFragment != null) {
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, mInstrumentsFragment);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            viewModel.recordForegroundFragment(mInstrumentsFragment);
                        } else {
                            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentInstruments_WWind");
                            if (fragment == null) {
                                mQuizFragment = FragmentInstruments_WWind.newInstance();
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, mQuizFragment, "FragmentInstruments_WWind");
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            } else {
                                mQuizFragment = fragment;
                                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
                                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (itemId == R.id.nav_btm_reference) {
                        viewModel.recordQuizBtnStatus(false);
                        if (mReferenceFragment != null) {
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, mReferenceFragment);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        } else {
                            mReferenceFragment = FragmentReference.newInstance();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, mReferenceFragment, "FragmentReference");
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        }
                    }
                        //Set Quiz-Ext button's visibility.
                        setQuizExtBtn();
                        //Call 'invalidateOptionsMenu' to set the Quiz-Exit button's visibility.
                        invalidateOptionsMenu();

                        return true;
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    /**Display FragmentInstruments_WWind when opening the app for the first time.
     * If the app is being resumed, use getForegroundFragment.
     */
    if (viewModel.getForegroundFragment() == null) {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FragmentInstruments_WWind");
        if (fragment == null) {
            mInstrumentsFragment = FragmentInstruments_WWind.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(mInstrumentsFragment, "FragmentInstruments_WWind");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        } else {
            mInstrumentsFragment = fragment;
        }
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, mInstrumentsFragment);
        transaction.commit();
        //Record foreground-fragment change
        viewModel.recordForegroundFragment(mInstrumentsFragment);
        //Set Quiz-Exit Status
        viewModel.recordQuizBtnStatus(false);
        //Set 'Reference' icon as checked
        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
    } else if (viewModel.getForegroundFragment() != null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment foregroundFragment = viewModel.getForegroundFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, foregroundFragment);
        transaction.commit();
        //Record foreground-fragment change, set bottom-navigation icon
        viewModel.recordForegroundFragment(foregroundFragment);
        String fragment = foregroundFragment.toString();
        if (fragment.contains("Quiz")) {
            bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
        } else if (fragment.contains("Reference")) {
            bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
        } else if (fragment.contains("Help")) {
            bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    //Actions onPause
    viewModel.recordInstrumentsFragment(mInstrumentsFragment);
}


//Search function handled here
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the options menu from XML
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);

    //Set 'Quiz Exit' button's visibility.
    boolean status = viewModel.getQuizBtnStatus();
    menu.findItem(R.id.ab_quiz_exit).setVisible(status);

    return true;
}


//Handle action-bar button clicks
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        case R.id.ab_quiz_exit:
            onQuizExit();

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**Parent Fragment**

```
public class FragmentInstruments_Brass extends Fragment {

public static FragmentInstruments_Brass newInstance() {
    FragmentInstruments_Brass fragment = new FragmentInstruments_Brass();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Fragment screen orientation normal both portrait and landscape
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_instruments, container, false);
    //Setting ViewPager for each tab
    ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager_instruments);
    tabsToViewPager(viewPager);
    //Set tabs inside toolbar
    TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabLayout_instruments);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, false);
    return view;
}

//Add Fragments to Tabs
private void tabsToViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    //Brass Fragments
    adapter.addFragment(new Inst_Br_Frag1(), "Name1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Inst_Br_Frag2(), "Name2");
    adapter.addFragment(new Inst_Br_Frag3(), "Name3");
    adapter.addFragment(new Inst_Br_Frag4(), "Name4");
    adapter.addFragment(new Inst_Br_Frag5(), "Name5");
    adapter.addFragment(new Inst_Br_Frag6(), "Name6");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

static class Adapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    //mFragmentList stores ChildFragments
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    //mFragmentTitleList stores the displayed name of each ChildFragment
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    Adapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    // Return the Fragment associated with a specified position
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    // getCount() returns the number of views available
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    //This method may be called by the ViewPager to obtain a title string to describe the specified page.
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @AdamJohns Nope, sorry.